# Transparent DIV Overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, here's what I'm trying to do :

- I have a page structure, with several `div`s, nested `div`s, etc
- I want to handle 2 different types of events : click *and* hover.
- For those 2 events, I want a transparent `DIV` overlay (with some colour tint?) above the aforementioned `div` covering all of it.

How can this be done?

Any ideas?

---

**Here's a fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/cFw7d/2/ <del>(though I somehow can't make it show properly - it's a jQuery Mobile page actually...)</del>

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with a dummy content?

Comment: Please specify more detail.  Do you want it over all div's, nested div's etc or only on specific one's or what?
Maybe add a jsfiddle.net of your structure and we can work on that to get you a solution.

Comment: OK, just give me a moment.

Comment: @HashemQolami Please have a look at the updated original question.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker What I need is something somewhat complicated : I'm basically targetting `[comp-id]` elements. When one clicks somewhere, we get the outermost NOT-already-selected `[comp-id]` element. Next time, when the user clicks again we'll go one level deeper. And so on... Is it by any means helpful?

Comment: @Itay Is it doable without an extra `div`?

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't fully understand what you're trying to do. You just want to color it?

Comment: I'm taking a look now.  In what instances should the DIV-overlay be removed?  Also what do you mean by one-level-deeper?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker OK, let's say the user clicks on the navigation bar. So far, all I can "capture" is the navigation item. What I need though is : a) user clicks there, the navigation *bar* is highlighted, b) when user clicks again, given that the bar (the parent) is highlighted, then we highlight the navigation bar item.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker If you're a Mac/Xcode user, this is the best example I can give you : it's the same as you select elements in the IB, e.g. on a Table View - first the NSScrollView, then the NSTableView, then the column, etc...

Comment: @Itay Nope, I'm trying to overlay a transparently colored `div` *on top* of `[comp-id]`ed elements - following the concept, as described to RobSchmuecker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for the :after pseudo class in this case.
Just add on the CSS the following:

```
.msp-selected-hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,120,0.4);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

You might want to create different classes for hover and clicks as well as targetting just certain elements.

Your edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cFw7d/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a block on top of another block, and be able to click on the block below, you will have to use `pointer-events: none` CSS3 property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events